# Negative values in timeseries when removing seasonal values with HoltWinters (R)

Tags: r, time-series

i'm new to R, so I'm having trouble with this time series data

For example (the real data is way larger)

```
data <- c(7,5,3,2,5,2,4,11,5,4,7,22,5,14,18,20,14,22,23,20,23,16,21,23,42,64,39,34,39,43,49,59,30,15,10,12,4,2,4,6,7)

ts <- ts(data,frequency = 12, start = c(2010,1))
```

So if I try to decompose the data to adjust it

```
ts.decompose <- decompose(ts)

ts.adjust <- ts - ts.decompose$seasonal

ts.hw <- HoltWinters(ts.adjust)

ts.forecast <- forecast.HoltWinters(ts.hw, h = 10)

plot.forecast(ts.forecast)
```

But for the first values I got negative values, why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are forecasting the *seasonally adjusted* time series, and of course the deseasonalized series `ts.adjust` can already contain negative values by itself, and in fact, it actually does.

In addition, even if the original series contained only positive values, Holt-Winters can yield negative forecasts. It is not constrained.

I would suggest trying to model your original (not seasonally adjusted) time series directly using `ets()` in the `forecast` package. It usually does a good job in detecting seasonality. (And it can also yield negative forecasts or prediction intervals.)

I very much recommend [this free online forecasting textbook](http://otexts.com/fpp/). Given your specific question, [this may also be helpful.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92443/can-a-mathematically-sound-prediction-interval-have-a-negative-lower-bound/)

Comment: Another related Q&A (specific for exponential smoothing): http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11202/27433